# TRIM & Remove Duplicate and TEXTJOIN a variable range using VBA

Tags: vba, duplicates, trim, textjoin

I would like a range most varying say `A1:A20` pulled from an application with space in beginning or in end so it need to be `TRIM` and then Remove Duplicates, remove blank cells and they need to be `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A20)`. Range is variable. So that I can copy paste this to QMF for running query.

Appreciate your help in creating this VBA so that I can create a button in the ribbon and can use in any excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub removeDuplicate()
 'removeDuplicate Macro

 Columns("A:A").Select
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), _ 
 Header:=xlNo 
 Range("A1").Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: Above provided vba only remove duplicate but does not TRIM nor remove blank cells nor do the textJoin the range. Also the range may not be in column (A:A) .Can be in any column by users selection of range.Appreciate an answer which should include these multiple criteria..